# How to change a UI.Button disabled color on runtime?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to change the opacity of my buttons disabled color with code in this exact loop so I was wondering how? Maybe sommething like how I disabled interactability. It should be done to tictactoeSpaces too.

```cs
        for(int i = 0; i < tictactoeSpaces.Length; i++)
        {
            tictactoeSpaces[i].interactable = false;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it need to be via code?

You actually can configure that in the [Inspector of the `Button` component](https://docs.unity3d.com/2020.1/Documentation/Manual/script-Button.html)

[image]

If you really need to do it on runtime you can change it via the [`Button.colors`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Selectable-colors.html) property like e.g.

```
var button = tictactoeSpaces[i];
var colors = button.colors;
var disabledColor = colors.disabledColor;
disabledColor.a = /*NEWALPHA e.g.*/ 0.2f;
colors.disabledColor = disabledColor;
button.colors = colors;

button.interactable = false;
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I have to do it in that loop so i unfortunately can't do it in the inspector. This was exactly what i was looking for.